# How to edit TextView Android?

Tags: android, webview, textview

I want to load a text file in Android with custom size and color just as shown in the website  (download the 1.html file). This is a HTML file and I have used WebView to show the file but I want to show using TextView. If I simply copy this in Text file it deletes the custom color and the size. Is there any easy way using Java code like loop or something to make specific lines in Red color and the other in black to make it look like it's shown in HTML File?

https://sites.google.com/site/gurbaniujagar/page1

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Nobody is going to open arbitrary links and download files. Post screenshots of what you want.

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site here, it shows you all you need to know.

http://javatechig.com/2013/04/07/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/